# getJSON callback not firing because of URL in one of the JSON elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson, jquery-callback

I have looked all over for an answer to this and I don't see one.

A little history of what I am working with. I am loading XML from one server, converting it to a JSON file on my server, so I can easily work with it (using JS).

My json looks like this:

```
{ "listings": [{ "detailsLink": "http://idx.firstidx.com/NewDetails.aspx?MLS=2529220&TableType=SingleFamily&DatabaseID=50&Domain=639 ", "detailsPrice": "149000", "detailsBeds": "0", "detailsBaths": "1", "detailsCity": "Floral Park", "detailsImage": "http://3pv.mlsstratus.com/mlsmultiphotos/full/1/220/2529220.jpg", "detailsState": "NY" }]}
```

My jquery looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('get-json.asp', function(data){
    $.each(data.listings, function(i,l){
        var detailsLink     = l.detailsLink;
        var detailsImage    = l.detailsImage;
        var detailsPrice    = l.detailsPrice;
        var detailsBeds     = l.detailsBeds;
        var detailsBaths    = l.detailsBaths;
        var detailsCity     = l.detailsCity;
        var detailsState    = l.detailsState;

    // Here is where I plan to do magical things with my new variables.

    });
});
```

The callback function isn't firing for me. When I remove the detailsLink from the JSON file it is firing without any issue. The detailsImage isn't causing an error.

I checked to see if my JSON was valid with a free service online and if I paste the JSON in by hand it comes up clean but when I load it from the URL it is showing the detailsLink to have an invalid character.

Is there something that I need to do to prepare my detailsLink (URL) for JSON output?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the VB for my ASP file:

```
Set listings = xml.getElementsByTagName("PropertyDetails")
        Response.Write "{"
        Response.Write " ""listings"": ["
        For i = 0 to (listings.Length-1)

            Response.Write "{"

            Response.Write " ""detailsPrice"":" &  " """ & listings.item(i).childNodes(11).text &  """, "
            Response.Write " ""detailsLink"":" &  " """ & listings.item(i).childNodes(0).text &  """, "
            Response.Write " ""detailsBeds"":" &  " """ & listings.item(i).childNodes(8).text &  """, "
            Response.Write " ""detailsBaths"":" &  " """ & listings.item(i).childNodes(9).text &  """, "
            Response.Write " ""detailsCity"":" &  " """ & listings.item(i).childNodes(4).text &  """, "
            Response.Write " ""detailsImage"":" &  " """ & listings.item(i).childNodes(15).text &  """, "
            Response.Write " ""detailsState"":" &  " """ & listings.item(i).childNodes(6).text &  """ "

        if i < (listings.length-1) then 'If this is not the last listing add a comma after the curley brace

            Response.Write "},"
            else
             Response.Write "}" 'This is the last listing, so no comma
        end if
        Next
        Response.Write "]"
        Response.Write "}"
```

Comment: What's the console say when it's failing?

Comment: This JSON is misformed because the left hand side has `{[{` but the right hand side closes with `}}]}` and there is no `{` in the middle to balance.

Comment: That's the thing, it is saying 200 OK. It is loading the data, I can inspect it using the DOM inspector but the callback isn't 'calling back'. 

Even if I try to console.log('Test'); it doesn't work.

Comment: @KevinB You mean, after the edit.

Comment: Add an error callback, but i'm pretty sure it's going to say "parseerror"

Comment: It was invalid Paul, I just fixed that. It was a result of my bad copy paste job.

Comment: OK.  Well, I don't see anything odd in the URLs.

Comment: Characters in strings, or elsewhere, that have a special meaning in JSON will usually be escaped by `JSON.stringify()` or similar routines in other languages.  For this reason, it is best not to write a JSON generator but to rely on language or library routines that have this escaping and have been tested.  You've described in general terms how the JSON is generated, but is it assembled in the server as a string a little at a time or is it coming from a library or built-in like JSON.stringify>

Comment: @Paul The file is an ASP file and I actually wrote out each line inside of a for loop by hand. I will post my ASP above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after looking further in to this, I can see that I didn't have any JSON header info being read by my Jquery on the front side of the site.

Instead of writing that out by hand too, I decided to use a library that can do it for me on the VB (ASP) side.

The class that I used is located a: http://www.aspjson.com/

Thanks for the help you guys.